# Collaborative map editor and annotator

Tags: maps, annotation

I am looking for a piece of software which would allow an authorised group of people to edit a map and associated metadata collaboratively.

For example, a temporary structure could be added to the map, and then information associated with the structure (e.g., how many kilowatts of power are required, how many fire extinguishers are required, whether a risk assessment has been carried out etc.).

It should be possible to export the map, selected layers, and selected fields from the annotations (e.g., only kilowatts) as an image or PDF.

ScribbleMaps is one possibility. My preference is open source solutions, but other commercial alternatives for me to investigate might also be acceptable.